# C++ Accessing the members of a class which is the mapped_type in a std::map

Tags: c++, stdmap

Consider a `std::map<const char *, MyClass*>`.

How do I access a member (variable or function) of the `MyClass` object pointed to by the map?

```
// assume MyClass has a string var 'fred' and a method 'ethel'
std::map<const char*, MyClass*> MyMap;

MyMap[ "A" ] = new MyClass;
MyMap.find( "A" )->fred = "I'm a Mertz";  // <--- fails on compile
MyMap.find( "A" )->second->fred = "I'm a Mertz";  // <--- also fails
```

---

**EDIT** -- per Xeo's suggestion

I posted dummy code.  Here is the real code.

```
// VarInfo is meta-data describing various variables, type, case, etc.
std::map<std::string,VarInfo*> g_VarMap; // this is a global 

int main( void )
{ 
   // ........ g_VarMap["systemName"] = new VarInfo; 
   g_VarMap.find( "systemName" ).second->setCase( VarInfo::MIXED, VarInfo::IGNORE ); 
   // ..... 
}
```

errors were:

```
struct std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, VarInfo*> >’ has no member named ‘second’
Field 'second' could not be resolved Semantic Error make: *** [src/ACT_iod.o] Error 1 C/C++ Problem
Method 'setCase' could not be resolved Semantic Error –
```

Comment: `char const*` is a *very* bad key type. You'll only ever access the same value if you pass the *exact same string*. And I don't mean a literal string like `"A"`, which can have different pointer addresses even for the same content.

Comment: Oh duh, I see what you mean.  Will a std::string work better here?

Comment: `std::string` is the correct choice here. Also, what are the exact compiler errors?

Comment: @thb  First, see the corrected code.  To answer the question, though, as I understand it, MyMap.find( "A" ) returns a reference to the mapping pair, and the .second should return the value stored in the second pair member which should be the pointer to the MyClass object somewhere on the heap.  Add -> to that pointer and get to 'fred' or 'ethel'.

Comment: The second version should compile just fine: http://ideone.com/jD0MW

Comment: You wrote the correct code in the question (`map.find(key)->second->member`), but reading your last comment, it seems you actually wrote `map.find(key).second->member` in your code. Please provide the actual code you use.

Comment: Ok, rather than the simplified code I tried to use, here is the actual stuff:

    // VarInfo is meta-data describing various variables, type, case, etc.
    std::map<std::string,VarInfo*>      g_VarMap;  // this is a global
    
    int main( void )
    {
       // ........
       g_VarMap["systemName"] = new VarInfo;
       g_VarMap.find( "systemName" ).second->setCase( VarInfo::MIXED, VarInfo::IGNORE );
       // .....
    }
     
errors are in the next comment - won't fit here

Comment: ‘struct std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, VarInfo*> >’ has no member named ‘second’
Field 'second' could not be resolved    Semantic Error
make: *** [src/ACT_iod.o] Error 1       C/C++ Problem
Method 'setCase' could not be resolved  Semantic Error

Comment: I recommend editing that into your question. :)

Comment: @Xeo, you were right.  Someone left a comment here (that seems to have disappeared) suggestin '.' instead of '->'.  So I tried that, and it failed.  Fixing both the '.' and changing 'const char *' to std:;string as suggested by you earlier fixed the bug.  Many Thanks.  If you'll repost your comments as an answer, I'll check it as best answer.

Comment: @Xeo - I've been yelled at by the forum police for editing original questions.  Guess I could add it as a footer with big "EDIT" flags around it.....

Comment: Editing your question with additional information is what you *should* do. You just shouldn't completely change it. If anybody yelled at you for the former, they don't know what they're saying. On the answer thing, just accept any of the answers telling you the correct solution, I don't mind. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::map` stores types internally as a `std::pair`, and `std::map::find`, returns an `iterator`.  So, to access members of your class, you have to go through the `iterator`, which presents the `key_type` as `first`, and the `value_type` as `second`.  Also, as others have stated, you should probably *not* be using `const char*` as your `key_type`.  Here's a short example.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

struct T
{
   T(int x, int y) : x_(x), y_(y)
   {}

   int x_, y_;
};

int main()
{
   typedef std::map<std::string, T> map_type;
   map_type m;

   m.insert(std::make_pair("0:0", T(0,0)));
   m.insert(std::make_pair("0:1", T(0,1)));
   m.insert(std::make_pair("1:1", T(1,1)));

   // find the desired item (returns an iterator to the item
   // or end() if the item doesn't exist.
   map_type::const_iterator t_0_1 = m.find("0:1");

   if(m.end() != t_0_1)
   {
      // access via the iterator (a std::pair) with 
      // key stored in first, and your contained type
      // stored in second.
      std::cout << t_0_1->second.x_ << ':' << t_0_1->second.y_ << '\n';
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Much love for the downvote(s).  Care to explain?  Did I get something incorrect in your eyes?

Comment: Maybe I am hopelessly out of date, but I like your coding style.  I had never seen identifiers like `x_` and `y_` used systematically as you have done.  (I have seen `_x` and `_y`, but don't care for that style, since such identifiers look like internal implementation symbols.)  I may adopt the practice.

Comment: @thb: A trailing underscore is actually pretty common for member variables (I personally prefer a leading one).

Comment: I believe I was introduced to it in Scott Meyers excellent book, Effective C++.

Comment: @Xeo:  The advice is appreciated, and raises another question, please.  Does the leading underscore not look like an internal implementation symbol to you?  I mean, it isn't one, but doesn't it *look* too much like one for comfortable reading of source code, compiler-emitted error messages, etc.?

Comment: @thb: If it did for me, I wouldn't use it. :P I just personally didn't like the `m_` prefix for members and dropped the `m`. I do this mostly for autocompletion, so I just type `_` and get the private members listed.

Comment: FWIW, I like the m_, which I use for public members, and p_ for private one.  As a visually impaired person, a leading '_' often disappears into the noise (commas, braces, brackets...), while m_ seems to not. Don't quite know why.  I do like to separate stuff with spaces to make seeing individual items easier and I'll bet I WANT to see the '_' as a space.

Comment: I'm confused, the question states that the user tried using "second" to access the value type, but got the error `iterator... has no member named ‘second’`. I'm seeing the same error on my system with similar code. I'm tempted to downvote your answer unless you can provide a better explanation.

Comment: -1 because while your code sample is correct, your explanation fails to address the error. The problem is that iterator is a pointer type, not a reference type, so he needs to use `iter->second` instead of `iter.second`. This simply is not the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

It fails because `std::map<T, Y>::find()` returns an iterator, not a reference to an MyMap object. The correct code would be:

```
map<const char*, MyClass*>::iterator a;
a = MyMap.find("A");
// a->fred; this is wrong too
a->second->fred = "Whatever";
```

Comment: "returns an iterator, not a reference to an iterator" -- makes no sense. Did you mean "a reference to a pair"?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious method is

```
MyMap[key]->fred
```

, but

```
MyMap.find( key )->second->fred
```

should also work.  In both cases, you must ensure that the key is 
present before using it.  In the code you've written, it (usually) won't
be, since you're using the address of a specific instance of a string
literal as key; a compiler is allowed to merge instances with the same
value, but is not required to.

Comment: No, in the `MyMap[key]` version, the key is not required to be present already.

Comment: Yes, because `MyMap[key]` will insert a null pointer if the key isn't already present; dereferencing the null pointer is undefined behavior, and once the map starts containing null pointers, you have to make an additional check every time you extract something from the map.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that an iterator is a pointer type, not a reference type, so `iter.second` will fail to compile.

Instead, you must use the pointer syntax: `iter->second` (arrow instead of dot).

Consider this short example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
   std::map<int, std::string> myMap;

   std::map<int, std::string>::iterator it;
   std::map<int, std::string>::iterator end = myMap.end();

   myMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(0, "hello"));
   myMap.insert(std::pair<int, std::string>(1, "world"));

   for(it = myMap.begin(); it != end; ++it)
   {
      // std::cout << "Value: " << it.second << "\n";
      // The previous line will fail to compile with error:
      //    ‘struct std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const int,
      //    std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
      //    std::allocator<char> > > >’ has no member named ‘second’

      // The following line is correct
      std::cout << "Value: " << it->second << "\n";
   }
}
```